# Returning a String from C to Python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, shared-libraries

I'm new to both C and Python, I'm trying to get the C function `getText()` into Python but all I'm getting are numbers

This is `foo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * getText(void)
{
    return "world hello";
}
const char * getText2(void)
{
    return "hello world";
}
```

And this is my python code from the terminal

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/user/dir/libfoo.so')
>>> testlib.getText()
743175865
```

I have already compiled the shared object and testing it with `puts("Hello world")` works as it appears in the terminal.

I'm sure I'm accessing the `getText()` wrongly from python but I don't know which one. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an example of how to handle string return types in the [`ctypes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types). Unless the foreign function returns and `int`, you need to set the return type for the foreign function with the `.restype` attribute. For your code:

```
import ctypes
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/user/dir/libfoo.so')
testlib.getText.restype = testlib.getText2.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
print testlib.getText()
print testlib.getText2()
```

**Output**

```
world hello
hello world
```

Answer (score -1):

your foo.c return local array instead you have to return a pointer to dynamically declared array using malloc.

```
const char * getText(char* name)
{    
  char hello[] = "world hello";
  char *var1 = malloc ( sizeof(char) * ( strlen(name) + strlen(hello) + 1 ) );
  if( var1 == NULL) exit(1);
   strcpy( var1 , hello);
   strcat(var1, name);    
   return var1;
 }
```

Comment: No. Since the returned strings are declared as literals they will exist in the string table in global address space, and therefore they will be accessible after the function returns.